# Unable to rename gnome terminal window after upgrading to Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: gnome-terminal, ubuntu-15.04

I am not able to rename terminal window after upgrading into Ubuntu 15.04. There are three options with the right click -

- Move Terminal Left
- Move Terminal Right
- Close Terminal

And there is no option 'Set title' which was present on previous versions of Ubuntu.

My gnome-terminal version is 3.14.2

Comment: I want to know why this question down voted as it was my concern when I upgraded from Ubuntu 14 to Ubuntu 15

Answer (score 5):

In case anyone is still looking,  The `.bashrc` solution [proposed by Kirby](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=740188#c6) worked for me too

```
set-title(){
  ORIG=$PS1
  TITLE="\e]2;$@\a"
  PS1=${ORIG}${TITLE}
}
```

then from trminal : `$ set-title your-title`

Answer (score 2):

There's an answer over here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/616404/ubuntu-15-04-fresh-install-cant-rename-gnome-terminal-tabs

In summary: The option was removed :/  There are some workarounds, of various levels of clunkiness.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and found that there is no easy way to set the tab title using right click of a mouse (the way I and most of my colleagues are used to). It was so irritiating at the sametime :(. So in our case, the solution was to switch the terminal. So I searched for many alternatives like sakura, etc and finally settled on the xfce-terminal. You can use the below command to install it:

```
sudo apt-get install xfce4-terminal
```

It provides the option to set the tab title by right click, it provides profile feature, and has all the other features similar to Gnome terminal.